# Cannot run docker images

Tags: docker, fedora, docker-run

I install docker community on my new laptop running Fedora 31. I followed the guide given here : https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/fedora/. 
All was good until I tried to run the hello-world image or a mysql image. I did this in order to avoid the use of sudo every time but that's all.

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

When I use

```
docker run hello-world
```

The return is :

```
de42c60db0a02e91977cb959b3467aa1bb7ca00fa009a95256615a31c55fe395
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: 
starting container process caused "process_linux.go:297: applying cgroup configuration for 
process caused \"open /sys/fs/cgroup/docker/cpuset.cpus.effective: no such file or 
directory\"": unknown.
```

Anyone know how to solve this ? Big thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to run :

```
sudo dnf install -y grubby && \
  sudo grubby \
  --update-kernel=ALL \
  --args="systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
```

and reboot, source [here](https://medium.com/nttlabs/cgroup-v2-596d035be4d7)

Comment: Are you saying docker doesn't run without systemd? I got the same error without running Fedora OR systemd.

Wait, actually the file is just /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/docker/cpuset.cpus for me.